# IBM Watson Assistant: How to integrate a chabot into a WIX web site?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I've created a Watson Assistant chatbot, but I do not have any idea about how integrate it into a Wix website? I didi it in slack, facebook messenger and a wordpress website but in WIx I cannot find any clue how to do it? could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the instructions from "[Integrating the web chat with your webseite](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-chat)". It shows how you can embed the IBM Watson Assistant chatbot via a HTML widget.

Basically, you have to add a JavaScript to your web page. That script can be parameterized. It loads the actual chat script which shows off the chatbot.